Printing Floating point value with commans ( IE : 1,000 ) in c
So I want to print out a floating point value in c which would be used for a currency, and I would like it to separate it with , so it would show something like £1,000 ( as an example). I have been trying to do some research on my own however I cant seem to find any solution.
printf("| %s %5d %s | %s %12.12s %s | %s %c%8.2f %s  | %s     %6d %s      | %s %6d %s  |\n",
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].id,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].model,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   POUND_SYMBOL,
   cars[index].price,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].yearOfManufacture,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].amountInStock,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR);

I would be putting the value in this piece of code. Which prints out the car values in a table.
I already tried using features like commas such as this while using set local however it didn't work. Thanks in advance
printf("| %s %5d %s | %s %12.12s %s | %s %c%'.2f %s  | %s     %6d %s      | %s %6d %s  |\n",
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].id,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].model,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   POUND_SYMBOL,
   cars[index].price,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].yearOfManufacture,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR,
   OUTPUT_LIGHT_GREEN,
   cars[index].amountInStock,
   OUTPUT_WHITE_COLOUR);


Thousand-separator is usually a locale (region) setting in the OS.

Please provide a [mre]. One that doesn't rely on data we don't have. One that doesn't obfuscate the question with irrelevant details, like colors. So, one that contains only what is strictly needed to see your point. But that contains all that is needed (including #include <stdio.h> and stuff). We should be able to copy&paste your code, compile and run it, and see for ourselves what you see

Plus, you didn't really ask a question here. What is your question? Why what you've tried doesn't work? What have you tried exactly (it is really hard for me to tell that from that huge line of code where it is not clear what is the amount you want to print). Are you looking for the correct %thing  to use? Or trying to understand why the correct one doesn't work?

On my linux system things like %'.2f (ior even just %f with correct decimal point separator) works only if I first #include <locale.h> and then setlocale(LC_ALL, "");. Which is, I believe, the standard (the "C" locale isn't named C for no reason. It is the default locale, even if you configured your system otherwise). On my Mac, it is even worse: even doing so, printing of amounts is incorrect, because MacOS locale files are false (so it is incorrect in my country, France. I can't speak for other counties, of course). So I use Norway locale for amounts, and french locale for the rest..

And that is for 2 unix systems. I have no idea how it would work on windows (where it probably depends on whether this is native windows or WSL... but well, I know nothing of that, I haven't owned a Windows machine since Windows 3.11) So, point is, it is really system dependent, so you need also to clarify what system you are on. And if you wan't to be system independent, I am afraid the simplest method would be to write your own amount2string function
